# Can't install Python 3 on Windows XP

Tags: windows, python-3.x

Does Python 3 support Win XP? Because I'm switching from Python 2 to 3, but I cannot install it. I've downloaded Python 3.3.2 Windows x86 MSI Installer, I open it and it says "Preparing to install...", later I select "Install just for me (not available on Vista)", click "Next" and the installer suddenly closes (also if I select "Install for all users"). When closed, a message appears saying "Send report errors? - Don't send". I'm running Windows XP SP 3 32 bits. I have also installed Python 2.7, that's a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by extracting the `.msi` file with [this tool](https://code.google.com/p/lessmsi/) and moving the files manually to `C:\Python33`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best is to uninstall python 2.7 before and after try again.

Comment: But I've been developing with Python 2.7 three years. All my projects, packages and modules goes with Python 2.7. The idea was to keep both installed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this version: http://www.activestate.com/activepython. It's work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the last release supporting Windows XP was

> Python 3.4.3 - Feb. 25, 2015

After that you see the note at the end of the download sections for each version

> Note that Python 3.5.0 cannot be used on Windows XP or earlier.

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/